# Easing function with Google Maps FitBounds() function

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3

Is it possible when calling `map.fitBounds()` to use an easing function to ensure a smooth change of view on the map?

Answer (score 2):

Not easily.  It's not very easy to "animate" the transition of zoom levels / map center and the `fitBounds` function doesn't provide any options to enable this.

If you wanted to do this yourself, your best bet would be to calculate the best center and zoom level and then write some jQuery to animate the setCenter calls.  The zoom level adjustments would be tricky because there are rather discrete changes.  jQuery can't animate smoothly zooming from 1 -> 3 because the only step tiles will be served for is 2.

Comment: hope Google will add map.fitBounds(bounds, speed) // 0 is the current behavior

Answer (score 1):

What about `map.panToBounds(latLngBounds:LatLngBounds)`?  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Map

Comment: This is not really the same: panToBounds does nothing when the bound is already in the viewport. It does not center the bound, neither does it zoom to get the bound to fit nicely.

Comment: Like Sjeiti said, this simply moves (pans) the current view (at current zoom level) to include the bounds. It does not fit (zoom & center) to the bounds.

Answer (score 1):

Given that the `map.fitBounds` transitioning seems to be reasonably smooth when the amount of zooming and panning is not too important, it should be possible to write a function that does a step-by-step animation through a number of intermediate LatLngBounds. The Map class has an `idle` event which would tell when to start the next step.